# How do I re-use this input type when the create mutation has required fields but updates don't?

Tags: graphql, apollo-server

Input types seem useless to me. **I am trying to remove the redundancy between NewUserInput and UserInput** because they're practically the same thing.

When I go to "create" a user all the fields are required, but the user may not want to update all their fields so the required fields become optional in the update mutation.  GraphQL obviously won't let me run the query if I don't fill in the required arguments.

Am I just trying to reuse the input where its not supposed to be reused?

The only way I can think to reuse inputs is to not have anything required and just verify required fields in the resolvers... which doesn't seem right either so I can't figure out how input types are reusable.

Schema:

```
type Mutation {
  createUser(input: NewUserInput!): User
  deleteUser(userId: ID!): User
  updateUser(userId: ID!, input: UserInput!): User
}

input NewUserInput {
  firstName: String!
  email: String!
  age: Int
}

input UserInput {
  firstName: String
  email: String
  age: Int
}

type User {
  id: ID!
  firstName: String!
  email: String!
  age: Int
}
```

Resolvers (just using an array):

```
Mutation: {
    createUser: (parent, args, context, info) => {
      const userAlreadyExists = users.some((elem) => {
        return elem.email == args.email;
      });

      if (userAlreadyExists) {
        throw new Error("User already exists");
      } else {
        const newUser = {
          id: newUserId(),
          firstName: args.input.firstName,
          email: args.input.email,
          age: args.input.age,
        };
        users.push(newUser);
        return newUser;
      }
    },
    updateUser: (_, args) => {
      const userIndex = users.findIndex((elem) => elem.id == args.userId);
      users[userIndex] = { ...users[userIndex], ...args.input };
      return users[userIndex];
    },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The only way I can think to reuse inputs is to not have anything required and just verify required fields in the resolvers.

This method is used in `WPGraphQL` ... to customize input validation errors ...

> Am I just trying to reuse the input where its not supposed to be reused?

Right, looks like a problem for manually written code while more often generated ... `WPGraphQL` still defines separate input types for create and update mutations ... because update input usually contains `id` field ... and both can be extended separately.